# Print percentage of task completed from foreach loop

Tags: unix, awk, foreach, tcsh

I am processing a file content using a foeach loop in unix environment and I would like to print the percentage of task completed in a single line on the xterm. something like an increasing counter.

```
foreach xxx (`cat file1`)
 set total = `wc -l file1`
 # count definination 
 # print percentage completed => count/total
end
```

Content of file1 is some test in a single column

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

Output expected is

```
> 25%
> 50%
```

updated numbers overwrite the previous status on the same line. something like a live ticker

Comment: Are you using tcsh?

Comment: Add your shell and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: I am using tcsh and output is

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have discovered that satisfies my requirements

```
set ccc = 0
foreach xxx ( `cat file1 ` )
set nnn = ` wc -l file1`
set ccc = `expr $ccc + 1`
echo $ccc $nnn | awk '{printf ("\r%-5s completed out of %s",$1,$2)}'
end
```

The key element that worked for me is '\r' option in the print command, this option would replace the text on the current line.

Comment: Why not just do everything inside awk, instead of doing harm? (See [this](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html) or [this](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt) or [this](https://www.shlomifish.org/open-source/anti/csh/)).